# Como descobrir qual template o WordPress está usando numa página do site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Muitas vezes não tenho certeza exatamente qual arquivo do theme está gerando uma página do site, por exemplo, `http://example.com/nome-da-pagina-post`.

O que faço é colocar um `echo` dentro de cada template do theme, `single.php`, `archive.php`...

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

get_header();
echo 'SINGLE.PHP'; ?>
```

Tem algum jeito mais fácil?

Comment: Bom ver-te por aqui de novo!

Comment: salve salve, Sergio :)

Comment: Viva o brasofilo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hey, @big, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

A variável global `$template` contém essa informação. Podemos colocar um filtro no `the_content` para imprimir isso e fazer com que só apareça para o administrador:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sopt_print_template', 20 );

function sopt_print_template( $content ) {
    # O valor da global $template vai ser tipo:
    # /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/template-name.php
    global $template;

    # Não executar o filtro se estivermos no backend 
    # ou se o usuário não for um administrador
    if( is_admin() || !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        return $content;

    # Buscar o nome da pasta e do arquivo
    $split_path = explode( '/', $template );
    $total = count( $split_path ) - 1;
    $theme_and_template = $split_path[$total-1] . '/' . $split_path[$total];
    $print = '<strong style="font-size:1em;background-color:#FFFDBC;padding:8px">Current = ' . $theme_and_template . '</strong>';

    # Adicionar a informação antes do conteúdo
    $content = $print . $content;
    return $content;
}
```

#### Página principal do site: usando `index.php` do child theme

> [image: child theme index.php]

#### Vendo um post simples: o child theme **não** tem `single.php`, site usando o arquivo do parent theme

> [image: parent theme single.php]

---

Outra opção é imprimir essa informação como um comentário HTML na `<head>`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'sopt_print_template_in_head', 999 );    

function sopt_print_template_in_head() {
    global $template;
    echo '
    <!--

    TEMPLATE = ' . $template . '

    -->
    ';
}
```